# Counting the Maximum Number of Values

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data table Employees, I want to show all the employees who have been hired on the same day on which the maximum number of employees has been hired. Here's my code:

```
select last_name, hire_date, count(*) as "Number of Employees Hired" 
from employees
group by last_name, hire_date
where hire_date = max(count(*));
```

However, this code shows "SQL Command Not Properly Ended" error when I run it. How do I fix it so that it runs correctly?

Comment: What database - oracle, and what version?

Comment: @ OldProgrammer This is Oracle SQL Developer, version 4.1.5.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest way, but I think will do the trick:

```
SELECT last_name,
  max_hire.hire_date,
  max_hire.cnt
FROM
  (SELECT *
  FROM
    (SELECT hire_date,
      COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY hire_date
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    )
  WHERE rownum = 1
  ) max_hire
INNER JOIN employees
ON employees.hire_date = max_hire.hire_date
```

Comment: Thanks OldProgramme! Looks convoluted but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use `WHERE` before the `GROUP BY` clause and secondly you should use the aggregate function (`count`) correctly, as in your case `count(*)` cannot be compared within the `WHERE` clause.

You can go with the approach below without using where: (**Tested under MySQL**)

```
select last_name, hire_date, count(*) as "Number of Employees Hired" 
from employees
group by last_name, hire_date
Order by "Number of Employees Hired" desc limit 1
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: @OldProgrammer that's why I mentioned 'Tested Under MySQL'. I am pretty sure Tim can convert the query on whatever platform he is using.